# MathJax in Comments, Titles

Tags: feature-request, ios-app, mathjax

On the latest iOS StackExchange app, math symbols are not rendered at all in the titles and comments, while they work properly on the website. It's often useful to see, at a glance, what a question is about by looking at the math in the title, and comments are hard to read without the MathJax rendering. Is anyone working on this?